# Android App Rejected due to links to Lyrics - Musixmatch

Tags: android, musixmatch

Google have rejected my music radio app due to the Search button links to Spotify, Apple Music, Deezer and Lyrics- Musixmatch lyrics, specifically Lyrics - Musixmatch, stating that it is in breach of Google Guideline policies. If the user does not have this application, then my application opens the market and I do not understand where is the hype. I had the app resubmitted elaborating this but Google have again rejected the app.
Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: i dont think you will find answers to playstore questions here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746